# JQuery Autocomplete on Ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding, autocomplete, listener

I would like to use the JQuery's autocomplete plugin on a input box loaded using Ajax:

I have tried to achieve that using the following code, however it only works when the users clicks twice into the input :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#auto').live('keydown', function(){
        $(this).autocomplete(
          "/autocomplete",
          {
            delay:10,
            minChars:2,
            matchSubset:1,
            matchContains:1,
            cacheLength:10,
            onItemSelect:selectItem,
            onFindValue:selectItem,
            formatItem:formatItem,
            autoFill:true
        });
    });
});
```

Could you tell me if there is something wrong with my code?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not try $("#auto").focus(function(){...}); ?

Answer (score 3):

The solution given in question had one issue.
It executes auto-complete only after second character, because the first character can not be used for auto-complete query, thus this is the one which triggers `keydown` and executes registration of the control for auto-complete.

Following code attaches to all (matching) existing and newly created (Ajax) element's `focus` event, and performs `autocomplete()` registration after you click or tab into the input:

```
$(document).delegate(":input[data-autocomplete]", "focus", function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: $(this).attr("data-autocomplete"),
    });
})
```

in this example the selector find all elements having attribute `"data-autocomplete"`, the same attribute is used as source url:

```
<input id="1" data-autocomplete="++URL++">
```

**Importarnt:**
Depending on version you could use either `live()`, `delegate()` or `on()` function at the first place. Signatures of these three are slightly different, but it's quite easy to figure out how they map to each other:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#auto').live('keydown', function(){

    $( "#auto" ).autocomplete({
    source: data,
    minLength: 3
    });
```

});

Above worked for me...

Comment: This works only if `minLength`>1. The reason is that first char can not be used for auto-complete query, because this is the one which triggers `keydown` and executes registration of the control for `autocomplete`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the live()-function in your example will bind the keydown-event so that it applies the autocomplete only after you've triggered it. Try skipping the live() and go with only the autocomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#auto').autocomplete(
       "/autocomplete",
       {
            delay:10,
            minChars:2,
            matchSubset:1,
            matchContains:1,
            cacheLength:10,
            onItemSelect:selectItem,
            onFindValue:selectItem,
            formatItem:formatItem,
            autoFill:true
       }
    );
});
```

Comment: This won't quite work because the OP is trying to apply the widget to content loaded via AJAX.

Comment: Yes, I think it would only work if the input field was loaded with the page.

Comment: Agree with @mnml this the common way of attaching, which does not work in case of ajax content - and exactly this is the subject of this question.